# How Oracle update statistics data?

Tags: oracle11g, statistics

Oracle instance version: "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production"

- Create a new table[ord], nothing in the table, we use [select * from ord] to check the statistics, the cost is 2
- We insert 1000 records into [ord] table and execute the following script to gather the statistics, now the cost is 9

  > EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('COREBM','ORD',degree =>
  >   4,estimate_percent => null,method_opt => 'for all columns',cascade =>
  >   TRUE);
- Then we clear the data in [ord] table([delete from ord]), ensure the changes committed, then execute [EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(...)] again to gather the statistics, we see the cost is still 9 which is different than what I am expecting as 2

After all the data in the [ord] table are removed,and we gathered the statistics information, I do not understand why the cost of the [ord] table is still 9 even there is nothing in that table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your query is doing a full scan of the table, that means that it has to read every block up to the high water mark of the table.  The high water mark is not reset when you do a simple `DELETE` of data-- Oracle assumes that you are likely to insert more data in the future so it does not incur the cost of releasing extents as you delete data only to need to reacquire them shortly thereafter.  This means, though that the full table scan is just as costly when you have 1000 rows of data as when you subsequently have 0 rows of data with the same high water mark.  So you would expect that the cost would be the same after running the `DELETE`.

If you want to reset the high water mark, you can `TRUNCATE` the table rather than simply deleting the data.  This isn't something that you would do normally but it could be used for this sort of proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. Why I have this question is because I am working on a benchmarking project which testing the performance of the different aspects of our system. We designed different SQLs with different data set for performance testing, so we need to load different data set and run corresponding SQL to gather the performance statistics

Comment: so the process is like this:

 - Load the data set for TASK A, gather the Oracle statistics information, then run the SQL for TASK A  
 - Clean all the data set for TASK A and load the data set for TASK B, gather the Oracle statistics information again, then run the SQL for TASK B

As the statistics would heavily affect the execution plan generated by CBO, so is that possible to gather the statistics to reflect the real data statistics in the database once we loaded the data set for task B?

Comment: @user1929982 - I'm not sure I understand.  If your actual database is going to be doing both task A and B in the same set of tables, unless you are going to repeatedly truncate the tables in prod, you'd want to benchmark queries for both tasks with reasonable high-water marks.  If what you're really talking about are tables that store transient data, though, you probably want to use global temporary tables with an aggressive dynamic sampling setting.

Comment: The data set for different tasks are very different, and we will verify every task one by one(with different data set and different SQL), when running each task 1) load data set  2) **gather the Oracle statistics, we want the current statistics information reflect the latest statistics** 3)run the SQL for this task 4)cleanup all the data loaded in step 1.  then repeat 1~4 for another task. The key problem is when we are running the second tasks, how can we COB get the latest statistics for the new data set?

Comment: @user1929982 - But, like I said in my answer, if you are merely deleting data, the table is the same size whether there are 0 rows of data or 1000 rows of data.  The optimizer is using the most current information about the state of the table, the prior task simply extended the high water mark. Are you asking how to get the optimizer to use incorrect statistics so it thinks that table scans are cheaper than they actually are?  That seems unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: I am quite new to Oracle, please correct me if I am not understand it correctly, so the cost of the table scan is based on the how much space that table is occupied instead of how much data in that talbe?
What I am expecting is how can we tell the CBO that the [ord] table is empty now, so the cost for that table should be 0